# Fixing the problem of passing data from one servlet to another

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have writen a code of a jsp-page, two servlets and a final page.
The jsp-page sends data from the form to the first servlet (Controller) which sends it to the second one (AreaCheck) in its turn.
On the /controller page (see web.xml) an error 405 "HTTP method POST is not supported" occurs.

index.jsp:

```
<script>
    function clickCheckbox(numbid){
        var currentCB = document.getElementById(numbid);
        if (currentCB.checked === true){
            document.getElementById('hidden_x').value = numbid;
        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('hidden_x').value = "";
        }
    }
</script>
            <form action="controller" method="post" id="form"  onsubmit="check(); return true;" novalidate>

                <label class="instructions" for="hidden_x"> Insert X: </label>
                <p><input type="checkbox" class="button" name="button_x" value="-5" id="-5" onclick="clickCheckbox(-5)"> -5 </p>

                <input type="hidden" name="hidden_x" id="hidden_x" value=""> <br>


                <label for="yCoordinate" class="instructions"> Insert Y: </label>
                <input type="text" id="yCoordinate" name="yCoordinate" autocomplete="off">

                <label class="instructions" for="radius"> Insert R: </label>
                <select id="radius" name="radius">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                </select>
                <br>

                <p id="button" class="input_button">
                    <input type="submit" value="Check the result.">
                </p>
            </form>
```

ControllerServlet.java:

```
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String X = req.getParameter("hidden_x");
    String Y = req.getParameter("yCoordinate");
    String R = req.getParameter("radius");

    req.setAttribute("XCoordinate", X);   
    req.setAttribute("YCoordinate", Y);
    req.setAttribute("Radius", R);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("areaCheck").forward(req, resp);
}}
```

AreaCheckServlet.java:

```
public class AreaCheckServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException{
    String x = (String) req.getAttribute("XCoordinate");
    String y = (String) req.getAttribute("YCordinate");
    String r = (String) req.getAttribute("Radius"); 
    //some other logic goes here

    req.getRequestDispatcher("result.html").forward(req, resp);
}}
```

Web.xml:

```
<!--Controller Servlet-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>App.Servlets.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/controller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!--Servlet that checks hitting the area-->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AreaCheck</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>App.Servlets.AreaCheckServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AreaCheck</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/areaCheck</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Only relevant code shown here. A logic of the program may seem strange, but it cannot be changed because it is the task.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AreaCheckServlet should support POST method for you to forward a post request to it.
Implement doPost in AreaCheckServlet as well